# How to use nativescript-markdown-view in SvelteNative?

Tags: nativescript, svelte-native

This is the package: [nativescript-markdown-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-markdown-view)

I'm currently using SvelteNative and I have a simple svelte-native-template created by following the steps [here](https://svelte-native.technology/blog/svelte-native-quick-start) and the app I'm developing is already large so there's no issues for `svelte-native`.

Now, I wanted to include this package into my project. I think using NativeScript in SvelteNative is possible since SvelteNative is powered by NativeScript, and Svelte is just a compiler. (Please correct me if I'm wrong 'cause I just think that; I'm not very sure about that.) However, I don't know how to mix the two to add this package.

I installed it into the project just as instructed on the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-markdown-view). But I'm currently getting the error below:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@nativescript/core/color/color' in '/Users/zeddrix/Documents/manatal-coop_svelte-native/node_modules/nativescript-markdown-view'
 @ ../node_modules/nativescript-markdown-view/markdown-view.js 5:14-55
 @ ./testPage.xml
 @ . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)(?<!\.\/\btests\b\/.*?)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$
 @ ./app.ts
```

I need help to connect/configure this package into my SvelteNative app. Thanks in advance.